# How to create Azure Windows images in Azure while keeping master VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

For my students in my teaching classes, I create short-lived Azure VM's based on an image that I have created using sysprep and captured. That all works great.

But my problem is that each time I sysprep and capture my master VM I lose it and that means that I have to recreate the master image from scratch each time I want to update it, and that takes many hours to do.

I have seen many fragile approaches by which they all seem to involve a lot of manual steps and low-level disk backup/copy/VHD's to get around this.

So my question is what is the best approach for me as a teacher to keep my master VM alive so that I don't have to re-create it from scratch each time I need to create a new image for my clones?

I am sure there must be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, I think you need to make a copy for your VM and then create the image from the copy VM, so your original VM will be alive. You can follow the copy steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/copy-vm). Then create the image as before.

You need to create a new image when you update your VM each time, all the VM would be created from the image. So it's the only way to do that.